# How to turn a double to a 64-bit integer bit by bit using unions

Tags: c, double, bit

I would like to store all bits of a `double` in a 64-bit integer in C.

I.e. the most significant bit should be the sign, after that the exponent, then the fraction.

I would like to use a union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest way to do this is to use `memcpy`.

```
double x = 123.456;
uint64_t y;
memcpy(&y, &x, sizeof y);
```

If you don't have `memcpy` at your disposal, you can use a `union`:

```
union {
    double d;
    uint64_t i;
} u;

double x = 123.456;
uint64_t y;

u.d = x;
y = u.i;
```

Comment: Thank you! This works perfectly. Unfortunately, I can not use this header file in this project. There is however a hint that there is also a way to do this using unions.

Comment: You can just copy 8 chars from `(char *)&x` to `(char *)&y` in a loop, roll your own little specialized `memcpy()`. Should even just result in a 64bit read and 64bit write or even nothing because the value just stays in a register.